# How do I calculate solution of differential equation $\ddot{y}+y=3cos\left (4t \right )$ if the begining values are $y(0)=0, y'(0)=1?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have calculated particual solution and that's $1/5cos/4t)$, but how do I calculate general solution using this begining values?

Comment: You're a bit mixed up here: you get the general solution and then you choose coefficients to satisfy the initial conditions. The general solution is of the form particular_solution+general_homogeneous_solution.

Comment: Do you know the complementary solution and particular solution and how to find them?

Comment: Since $$y_{\text{general}}=y_{\text{complementary}}+y_{\text{particular}}$$
You must to find the complementary solution. Also the particular solution must be $y_{\text{particular}}=-\frac{1}{5}\cos(4t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned you first find the homogenous solution by the characteristic equation method:
$$
\lambda^2+1=0\Rightarrow \lambda=\pm i
$$
And then find the particular solution, usually by inspection (which it seems like you did), $-\frac{1}{5}\cos(4t)$. Then we have the general solution of
$$
y(t)=y_h+y_p=c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)-\frac{1}{5}\cos(4t)
$$
Next plug in boundary conditions:
$$
y(0)=0\Rightarrow 0=c_1-\frac{1}{5}\Rightarrow c_1=\frac{1}{5}
$$
and 
$$
y'(0)=1\Rightarrow 1=c_2
$$
and we get the unique solution
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{5}\cos(t)+\sin(t)-\frac{1}{5}\cos(4t)
$$